# How can I pass a function when linking with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my React app I have a page which has a list of web items (`WebItems.js`) and on the page there is an `Link` which goes to a page for adding a new web item (`Add.js`).

```
const WebItems = () => (
       async function getWebItems() {
        const result = await httpGet('webitem/list');
        if (result.items) {
            setWebItems(result.items);
        }
    }

    return <>
         <Link
            to="webitem/list"
            Add
        </Link>
      </>
)
```

I need to pass the function `getWebItems()` to the Add component so that after a web item is added the list of web items gets updated.

I am more familiar with `@reach/router` although I need to use `react-router-dom` for this project.

I found [this blog post](https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-pass-props-in-react-router/) but I am unsure if this is what I need.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, but you can make `getWebItems()` function into module, export it and use it in all your components.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make this function a custom hook and re-use it?

// useWebItems.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function useWebItems() {

const [webItems, setWebItems] = useState([]);

async function getWebItems() {
  const result = await httpGet('webitem/list');
  if (result.items) {
    setWebItems(result.items);
    }
  }

return { getWebItems, webItems };

}

export default useWebItems;
```

// Add Component

```
import { getWebItems, webItems } from 'path/to/useWebItems.js';

// Do whatever you want with getWebItems, webItems
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [route state](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect/to-object) and the object form of the `to` prop for the `Link`.

```
const WebItems = () => (
  async function getWebItems() {
    const result = await httpGet('webitem/list');
    if (result.items) {
      setWebItems(result.items);
    }
  }

  return <>
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: "webitem/list",
        state: {
          getWebItems,
        },
      }}
    >
      Add
    </Link>
  </>
);
```

Use [`location`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) from the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) on the receiving route/component

```
const { getWebItems } = props.location.state;

...

getWebItems();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`

My Add.js component:

export default function Add({ props }) {

const { getWebItems } = props.location.state;

Comment: @VinylWarmth The consuming component needs to also receive route props by either being directly rendered by a `Route` or wrapped in the `withRouter` Higher Order Component, or since it appears to be a functional component, using [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation) react hook, like `const location = useLocation();` then `location.state.getWebItems`;